# My HTML and CSS files won't link

Tags: html, css

My HTML and CSS files will not link up. Both files are in the same folder.

HTML (Home.HTML)

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="/Webpage/Stylesheet.css" />
<title>Webpage</title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Stylesheet (Stylesheet.css)

```
body{
backround-color: #7894D6;
}
```

Comment: try it without the /Webpage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are in the same folder, then the href should just be:

```
href="Stylesheet.css"
```

Comment: Changed that but it still doesn't seem to change the background colour

Comment: You're missing a "g" in "background" ;)

Comment: Woops haha. It still won't change the background?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="Stylesheet.css" />
```